# What is the process to suggest Tag deletions?

Tags: support, tags

I'm looking at:
https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ipreinserteventlistener/info

It hardly seems like a tag that people will subscribe to. How can I suggest it being removed?

Comment: In general, suggest it here and clearly state why. So well done. :)

Comment: @Bart He doesn't need a meta question to get rid of this tag.

Comment: Myeah, amended my comment @Servy

Comment: Thanks guys, I did as suggested by @Servy

Comment: @Bart I still assert that a tag like this where it's pretty clearly crap, he knows it's crap, and there's only one question on it, he can just remove the tag.  There's no need for a meta question.  The meta question is useful if he really isn't sure if the tag should go away, rather than to ask someone else to make it go away for him.

Comment: In this specific case, sure. Yet the title (and the underlying support question) is *"What is the process to suggest Tag deletions?"*. My comment addresses that and only that. Otherwise I would have made it an answer @Servy. ;)

Comment: @Bart I think it's clear. I just didn't know that deleting the tag from the question would result in a tag purge at the end of the day. Had I known, in such a clear case, I wouldn't have asked meta in the first place. Servy was just giving a full answer that's useful to future visitors (more so in the answer than in the comment here)

Comment: For high-volume tag deletions, you can submit a [`burninate-request`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/burninate-request) here on Meta.

Comment: Welcome to the New Tag Deletionist Cabal, @Miquel.  Muahahaha....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the tag from the one question it is tagged to (by editing that question), and the tag will be automatically deleted at the end of the day (assuming it is still not tagged to any questions at that point in time).

If you are unsure *if* the tag should be removed from all of the questions that it is tagged to, or there are so many questions using the tag that you feel that you alone wouldn't be capable of editing those questions, then you can post a question on meta asking for help cleaning up that tag.